# redirect one domain to another with htaccess rules

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was wondering how i can redirect my users from my old domain to a new url

forexample

http://www.5.joblessbuddy.com/news.html

into this

http://www.1.joblessbuddy.hu/news.html

i did this on my htaccess but not working

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} http://www.5.joblessbuddy.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.1.joblessbuddy.hu$1 [R=301,L]
```

any suggestion would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?5\.joblessbuddy\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.1.joblessbuddy.hu/$1 [R=301,L]
```

btw: mod_rewrite cheat sheet v2 is your [friend](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2/pdf/).